# Stop universal linking out of iOS App

Tags: ios, wkwebview, ios-universal-links

I have an app with an embedded WKWebView and every time a user clicks an Amazon link in the WebView it opens the native Amazon App. Is there a way to stop links from opening other apps while in my app?

I've tried implementing the WKNavigationDelegate method:

```
    - (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler
```

However, Apple builds the index off of the the regular domain instead of a custom schema.

The reason I want to stop the universal links from opening in a different app is that I'm making a wishlist app which lets users add items from websites. Universal links effectively break this ability by opening the native app.

Comment: any leads on this?

Answer (score -1):

Stopping the deep linking isn't possible. It's an OS level feature that apps can't control.